# JPA :: orphanRemoval and Lazy Collections

Tags: jpa

Say I have an entity *A* with a **OneToMany** collection of *Bs* with **FetchType EAGER** and **orphanRemoval** set to **true**. When I call **EntityManager#merge** on a *A* object that was detached and had some *B* elements from its collection removed (while detached), the respective rows (whose entities are now missing from the collection) are deleted from the database (in JPA/Hibernate).

How exactly would that play out in the case of **LAZY** collections? When the **EntityManager** is asked to merge a modified *A* object how can it tell the difference between B entities that were explicitly removed from the collection versus B entities that were never fetched because of the **LAZY** fetch type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JPA implementation must keep a flag of collections there were initialized or still in lazy state.

Therefore if you merge a previously detached entity, the merge operation will inspect the collection and if *only* it is initialized then it will enumerate the contents to find the changes against the entity fetched from the database.

However, if you instantiate a new instance and pass that on to merge, then the collection will be treated as initialized and if the collection is empty then JPA will remove all the collection items.

Please stop by and try the new JPA implementation, Batoo JPA  http://batoo.jp - that is over 15 times faster then the current JPA implementations in the market.

Comment: Very clear. Is this behaviour defined in the JPA specification?

Comment: Not in that detail. But that's totally inferred from the spec.

Comment: Does it means than setting the collection to null won't trigger the cascade ?